# The client was unable to reuse a session with SPID XX, which had been reset for connection pooling

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

We have a recurring problem with one of our MS SQL Servers (Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3128.0 (X64) ).

The error message from the application log:

> Event Type: Error
>
> Event Source: MSSQLSERVER
>
> Event Category: (2)
>
> Event ID: 18056

The client was unable to reuse a session with SPID 94, which had been reset for connection pooling. This error may have been caused by an earlier operation failing. Check the error logs for failed operations immediately before this error message.

Anybody knows anything why this error occurs?

Our Sql Server Logs

> 07/18/2013 20:24:05,Logon,Unknown,Error: 18452 Severity: 14 State: 1.
>
> 07/18/2013 20:24:05,Logon,Unknown,SSPI handshake failed with error code 0x8009030c state 14 while establishing a connection with integrated security; the connection has been closed. Reason: AcceptSecurityContext failed. The Windows error code indicates the cause of failure. The logon attempt failed
>
> 07/18/2013 20:24:05,Logon,Unknown,Error: 17806 Severity: 20 State: 14.
>
> 07/18/2013 20:16:56,spid3076,Unknown,Fulltext thesaurus internal error (HRESULT = '0x00000002')
>
> 07/18/2013 20:16:56,spid3076,Unknown,Hata: 30049 Önem: 17 Durum: 1.
>   07/18/2013 20:16:56,spid3076,Unknown,Fulltext thesaurus internal error (HRESULT = '0x00000002')
>
> 07/18/2013 20:16:56,spid3076,Unknown,Hata: 30049 Önem: 17 Durum: 1.
>
> 07/18/2013 20:15:21,spid1823,Unknown,The client was unable to reuse a session with SPID 1823 which had been reset for connection pooling. The failure ID is 46. This error may have been caused by an earlier operation failing. Check the error logs for failed operations immediately before this error message.
>
> 07/18/2013 20:15:21,spid1823,Unknown,Error: 18056 Severity: 20 State: 46.
>
> 07/18/2013 20:15:21,Logon,Unknown,Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Failed to open the database 'xxx' configured in the login object while revalidating the login on the connection. [CLIENT: xxx]
>
> 07/18/2013 20:15:21,Logon,Unknown,Error: 18456 Severity: 14 State: 46.
>
> 07/18/2013 20:14:59,spid1179,Unknown,The client was unable to reuse a session with SPID 1179 which had been reset for connection pooling. The failure ID is 46. This error may have been caused by an earlier operation failing. Check the error logs for failed operations immediately before this error message.
>
> 07/18/2013 20:14:59,spid1179,Unknown,Error: 18056 Severity: 20 State: 46.
>
> 07/18/2013 20:14:28,Logon,Unknown,Error: 18456 Severity: 14 State: 46.
>
> 07/18/2013 20:10:54,spid947,Unknown,A timeout occurred while waiting for memory resources to execute the query in resource pool 'internal' (1). Rerun the query.
>
> 07/18/2013 20:10:54,spid947,Unknown,Error: 8645 Severity: 17 State: 1.
>
> 07/18/2013 20:10:54,spid1342,Unknown,A timeout occurred while waiting for memory resources to execute the query in resource pool 'internal' (1). Rerun the query.
>
> 07/18/2013 20:10:54,spid1342,Unknown,Error: 8645 Severity: 17 State: 1.
>
> 07/18/2013 20:10:54,spid190,Unknown,A timeout occurred while waiting for memory resources to execute the query in resource pool 'internal' (1). Rerun the query.
>
> 07/18/2013 20:10:54,spid190,Unknown,Error: 8645 Severity: 17 State: 1.
>
> 07/18/2013 20:10:54,spid184,Unknown,A timeout occurred while waiting for memory resources to execute the query in resource pool 'internal' (1). Rerun the query.
>
> 07/18/2013 20:10:54,spid184,Unknown,Error: 8645 Severity: 17 State: 1.
>
> 07/18/2013 20:10:54,spid226,Unknown,A timeout occurred while waiting for memory resources to execute the query in resource pool 'internal' (1). Rerun the query.
>
> 07/18/2013 19:59:11,spid1009,Unknown,The client was unable to reuse a session with SPID 1009 which had been reset for connection pooling. The failure ID is 46. This error may have been caused by an earlier operation failing. Check the error logs for failed operations immediately before this error message.
>
> 07/18/2013 19:59:11,spid1009,Unknown,Error: 18056 Severity: 20 State: 46.
>
> 07/18/2013 19:59:11,Logon,Unknown,Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Failed to open the database 'xxx' configured in the login object while revalidating the login on the connection. [CLIENT: xxx]
>
> 07/18/2013 19:59:11,Logon,Unknown,Error: 18456 Severity: 14 State: 46.
>
> 07/18/2013 19:59:08,spid664,Unknown,The client was unable to reuse a session with SPID 664 which had been reset for connection pooling. The failure ID is 46. This error may have been caused by an earlier operation failing. Check the error logs for failed operations immediately before this error message.
>
> 07/18/2013 19:59:08,spid664,Unknown,Error: 18056 Severity: 20 State: 46.
>
> 07/18/2013 19:59:08,Logon,Unknown,Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Failed to open the database 'xxx' configured in the login object while revalidating the login on the connection. [CLIENT: xxx]
>
> 07/18/2013 19:59:08,Logon,Unknown,Error: 18456 Severity: 14 State: 46.
>
> 07/18/2013 19:46:56,Logon,Unknown,Login failed for user 'live_score_2012'. Reason: Access to server validation failed while revalidating the login on the connection. [CLIENT: xxx]
>
> 07/18/2013 19:46:56,Logon,Unknown,Error: 18456 Severity: 14 State: 23.
>
> 07/18/2013 19:46:56,spid738,Unknown,The client was unable to reuse a session with SPID 738 which had been reset for connection pooling. The failure ID is 23. This error may have been caused by an earlier operation failing. Check the error logs for failed operations immediately before this error message.
>
> 07/18/2013 19:46:56,spid738,Unknown,Error: 18056 Severity: 20 State: 23.
>
> 07/18/2013 19:46:56,spid544,Unknown,The client was unable to reuse a session with SPID 544 which had been reset for connection pooling. The failure ID is 23. This error may have been caused by an earlier operation failing. Check the error logs for failed operations immediately before this error message.
>
> 07/18/2013 19:46:56,spid544,Unknown,Error: 18056 Severity: 20 State: 23.
>
> 07/18/2013 19:46:56,Logon,Unknown,Login failed for user 'live_score_2012'. Reason: Access to server validation failed while revalidating the login on the connection. [CLIENT: xxx]
>
> 07/18/2013 19:46:56,Logon,Unknown,Error: 18456 Severity: 14 State: 23.
>
> 07/18/2013 19:46:56,Logon,Unknown,Login failed for user 'elmah'. Reason: Access to server validation failed while revalidating the login on the connection. [CLIENT: xxx]
>
> 07/18/2013 19:46:56,Logon,Unknown,Error: 18456 Severity: 14 State: 23.
>
> 07/18/2013 19:46:56,spid799,Unknown,The client was unable to reuse a session with SPID 799 which had been reset for connection pooling. The failure ID is 23. This error may have been caused by an earlier operation failing. Check the error logs for failed operations immediately before this error message.
>
> 07/18/2013 19:46:56,spid799,Unknown,Error: 18056 Severity: 20 State: 23.
>
> 07/18/2013 19:46:56,Logon,Unknown,Login failed for user 'live_score_2012'. Reason: Access to server validation failed while revalidating the login on the connection. [CLIENT: xxx]
>
> 07/18/2013 19:46:56,Logon,Unknown,Error: 18456 Severity: 14 State: 23.
>
> 07/18/2013 19:46:55,spid143,Unknown,The client was unable to reuse a session with SPID 143 which had been reset for connection pooling. The failure ID is 23. This error may have been caused by an earlier operation failing. Check the error logs for failed operations immediately before this error message.
>
> 07/18/2013 19:46:55,spid143,Unknown,Error: 18056 Severity: 20 State: 23.
>
> 07/18/2013 19:46:55,Logon,Unknown,Login failed for user 'live_score_2012'. Reason: Access to server validation failed while revalidating the login on the connection. [CLIENT: xxx]
>
> 07/18/2013 19:46:55,Logon,Unknown,Error: 18456 Severity: 14 State: 23.
>
> 07/18/2013 19:46:55,spid739,Unknown,The client was unable to reuse a session with SPID 739 which had been reset for connection pooling. The failure ID is 23. This error may have been caused by an earlier operation failing. Check the error logs for failed operations immediately before this error message.
>
> 07/18/2013 19:46:55,spid739,Unknown,Error: 18056 Severity: 20 State: 23.
>
> 07/18/2013 19:46:55,Logon,Unknown,Login failed for user 'live_score_2012'. Reason: Access to server validation failed while revalidating the login on the connection. [CLIENT: xxx]
>
> 07/18/2013 19:46:55,Logon,Unknown,Error: 18456 Severity: 14 State: 23.

Comment: Can you please run the following and list out the messages that happened before and after the event mentionned above.  EXEC xp_readerrorlog 0 or what ever log file the error happens to be in. 1, 2, 3...

Comment: This question is NOT a duplicate of the other. Adding a reward to whoever provides the right answer.